# Timeout expired after calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql

I keep getting this error after the calling the stored procedure on mysql database :

> "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired. 
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout in IO
>   operation"

I know that the problem is related to the query it takes to long to execute so my question is this query it is good ? is there another way to optimize this stored procedure and make it return the data in relatively finite time:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mysql`@`%` PROCEDURE `UpadtePriceToCalibre`(IN Dos int(6),    IN Var varchar(50), IN PRIX double(10,4) , IN Cal int(6))
BEGIN
  insert into xxpch 
select `NuméroDossier`,`NuméroLot`,`Variété`,`Client`,`NF`,`Calibre`,`PrixKg`,PRIX,`NetFacture`,(PRIX * PoidNet),NOW()         
from detaildossier
where NuméroDossier = Dos AND Variété LIKE CONCAT('%',Var,'%') AND Calibre= Cal;
update detaildossier
SET PrixKg = PRIX 
    , NetFacture = (PRIX * PoidNet) 
    , PrixColis = (( PoidNet / NombreColis) * PRIX)
WHERE NuméroDossier = Dos AND Variété LIKE CONCAT('%',Var,'%') AND Calibre= Cal;
update aff_e ,cpv_d
set aff_e.netcpv =(select sum(cpv_d.prxtot) from cpv_d where cpv_d.numdos = Dos AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot)
    ,aff_e.mntvnt =(select sum(cpv_d.prxtot) from cpv_d where cpv_d.numdos = Dos AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot)
where  aff_e.numdos = Dos   AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot;
END
```

Comment: Not important but the correct term is "stored procedure"

Comment: This question needs a little work, this type of "*look at my lump of sql and tell me if its good*" question, is not a good fit for stack overflow. What is your schema, whats the execution plan, what indexes have you got, why do you have those indexes, have you run this through the performance tuner or profiler. Failing the really badly hewn sql, you could always just increase the timeout

Comment: The mysql command default to 30 seconds so you can change the timeout.

Comment: By upvoting a question you're saying _"This is a good, unique question that shows research effort, of which we should have more on the site"_. This is not such a question. See also @Michael's comment. Don't upvote questions like this.

Comment: The question has been edited, I think there is no problem with the form and it deserves some attention now.

Comment: @Zack it is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: Isn't there something wrong with the last update statement? It starts `update aff_e ,cpv_d` which would imply both tables being updated in a cartesian manner. But really it only needs to list `update aff_e` because cpv_d is not being updated. MYSQL isn't my thing, but that looks fishy to me and could maybe cause a timeout

Answer (score 1):

The first two  queries in the stored procedure look OK to me. Just an insert and an updates.

The final update query might take a bit longer because its summing multiple rows on another table. Its hard to tell without knowing more about the database whether that should run fast or not.

edit: Come to think of it, perhaps there is something wrong with the final update. Instead of:

```
update aff_e ,cpv_d
  set aff_e.netcpv =(select sum(cpv_d.prxtot) from cpv_d where cpv_d.numdos = Dos AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot)
    ,aff_e.mntvnt =(select sum(cpv_d.prxtot) from cpv_d where cpv_d.numdos = Dos AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot)
where  aff_e.numdos = Dos   AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot;
```

try:

```
update aff_e 
  set aff_e.netcpv =(select sum(cpv_d.prxtot) from cpv_d where cpv_d.numdos = Dos AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot)
  ,aff_e.mntvnt =(select sum(cpv_d.prxtot) from cpv_d where cpv_d.numdos = Dos AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot)
where  aff_e.numdos = Dos   AND cpv_d.numlot = aff_e.numlot;
```

I've got a feeling that adding cpv_d to the first line of the update statement might be causing problems, because it might cause lots of rows to get involved in the update that aren't needed.

Another idea: It could be that you've got some sort of locking or deadlock situation on your database and so your SP is timing out because of that. For example someone else running a big report could potentially (in certain conditions) lock parts of the tables you are trying to update and in situations like that, even fast stored procedures might time out.

As others have said, you could also just try increasing to timeout setting.

Welcome to ModOverflow!